# ActionListener: Disabling Buttons

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener

I am currently working on a Java class that produces a simple JFrame/JButton layout of Tic-Tac-Toe. Implementing ActionListener, I intended on having the selected JButton set its title to "X" or "O" (based on a boolean statement of whether or not it is X's turn to pick a JButton) and become disabled (so it cannot be played on top of in following turns). The current application I have created does this, but it will sometimes not change the JButton text or disable the button until I click another button. There does not seem to be any kind of cohesive order at which this happens when I click one of the JButtons. I have spent hours trying to fix this issue with no avail. Is there an issue with how I coded my actionPerformed method or how I added it to my JButtons?

Here is the code to my class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TTT extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

  // private fields
  private JButton[] buttonArray;
  private JLabel prompt;
  private boolean turnX;
  private String letter;



 public TTT() {
    // Instantiates JFrame window and adds lines to board
    super.setSize(235, 280);
    super.setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    // Instantiates JButton array
    buttonArray = new JButton[9];
    // Loop that creates the JButton squares
    for(int y = 30; y <= 140; y += 55) {
      for(int x = 30; x <= 140; x += 55) {
        for(int index = 0; index < buttonArray.length; index++) {
        buttonArray[index] = new JButton();
        buttonArray[index].setSize(50, 50);
        buttonArray[index].setLocation(x, y);
        buttonArray[index].addActionListener(this);
        super.add(buttonArray[index]);
      }  
    }
    }
    prompt = new javax.swing.JLabel("X's TURN");
    prompt.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    super.add(prompt);

    turnX = true;

    super.setVisible(true);
  } 

 public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent a) {

        // Calculate whose turn it is
        if(turnX){
            letter = "X";
            prompt.setText("O's TURN");
            turnX = false;    
        } else if(!turnX){
            letter = "O";
            prompt.setText("X's TURN");
            turnX = true;
        }
        JButton pressedButton = (JButton)a.getSource(); 
        pressedButton.setText(letter);
        pressedButton.setEnabled(false);
        super.repaint();
 }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TTT();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code:

```
for(int y = 30; y <= 140; y += 55) {
  for(int x = 30; x <= 140; x += 55) {
    for(int index = 0; index < buttonArray.length; index++) {
```

You are adding 82(!) JButtons (one on top of the other in groups of 9). So, what was actually happening was that one was changed (disabled etc), but on calling repaint, the order of painting them might change, so the one whose ActionListener was triggered was painted underneath one of the 8 that were still enabled and blank.

You can correct it like this:

```
...
int index = 0;   // <-- Add this line
for(int y = 30; y <= 140; y += 55) {
    for(int x = 30; x <= 140; x += 55) {
           // <-- remove the third for-loop
        buttonArray[index] = new JButton();
        buttonArray[index].setSize(50, 50);
        buttonArray[index].setLocation(x, y);
        buttonArray[index].addActionListener(this);
        super.add(buttonArray[index]);
        index++;   // <-- increment 'index'
    }  
}
...
```

You could also remove the `super.repaint()` line, since it is redundant.

---

Not directly related to your problem, but Swing related stuff should (for various reasons) be called from the **[Event Dispatching Thread (EDT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)**. One way to achieve this, is by using **[`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)**, so it might be a good idea to replace `new TTT();` with this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new TTT();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I lol'd when I read that I was adding 82 buttons to the JFrame...